# Are numbers also functions in functional programming?

Tags: function, functional-programming, language-agnostic, lambda-calculus

I have been taught in my Bsc course that in functional programming even numbers are functions that return themselves. I've read that lambda calculus consists only of functions and nothing else, so that would make sense. However, I didn't find any articles about functional programming that introduced numbers as functions. However(!), I also read that expressions in functional programming are functions and numbers are considered expressions, thus numbers must be functions...right?

In short, I am very confused about what is and isn't a function in functional programming.

Comment: If numbers were functions that return themselves, that would mean that returned value is also a function. That’s rather recursive. *Somewhere* there’s gotta be an actual numeric value involved.

Comment: No, in actual functional programming, numbers are numbers and functions are functions. *Implementations* may represent expressions as functions, but that is irrelevant, and those functions would certainly not return themselves.  The lambda calculus doesn't have numbers, but you can encode numbers in it however you like.  the Church Numerals are the standard way.

Comment: Church numerals are used in some of the lambda  calculus-based proof assistants and in dependent type systems, but there is no good reason to use them in more generic use cases.

Comment: nice blog post debunking this: http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell

Comment: What's actually true in functional languages is "everything is an expression, there are no statements".